# Last page number (Server side pagination, Ng2-Smart-Table)

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I'm using  Ng2-Smart-Table component with server side pagination.
I tested the example (https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/server/advanced-example-server.component.ts)

Analyzing the requests from the above examples, I noticed that no response comes from anything other than JSON records / objects:
[IMAGE - Response Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP0rE.png)

DOUBT: How does the component know which is the last page? (In example 500):
[IMAGE - Example last page pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xztTD.png)

I'm trying to understand to implement in my API, because I'll implement a bit different from the example, requesting only in the service. So I want to know how the component get the value of the last page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question XD
After debugging the component code in the server.data-source.js file I discovered how the component does, it does two validations and can extract the total of lines by two ways.
First it validates the response header if there is a Key equal to the value placed in the Key totalKey of the instance of the ServerDataSource object in your aplication angular.

If it does not exist it looks in the list of JSON objects of the response, also by the same key.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of paging is based on take and skip of data. Let say your grid showing 10 records then value of take will be 10 and if you are on first page then the value of skip will be zero. This is the following formulae used for this concept:

```
skip = (pageNo. - 1 ) * take
```

Hope it will help

Comment: The paging I got it.
Is not clear how the component knows that there are 500 pages (when I clicking in last page arrow), if in the response comes just the 10 items (because of take 10)?

Comment: They use index to render paging. They also use number of total records and page size to render pager. When  you use server side paging then you need to give total number of records to show actual paging because you only fetch limited number of records rather than whole records from database.

Comment: Okay man. I understood your point.
But my question is not about theory or how to calculate. But about HOW the component does to get the total value of pages.
I know that the API pass to it the total, but I want to understand HOW this is done, since in the documentation it does not appear and in the example that I tested it does not have any request with this parameter and none of the answers returns that total.